# Hyper-V dynamic memory using all memory with cache

Tags: ram, cache, hyper-v

Having trouble with Ubuntu server 18.04 and dynamic memory. I have some Debian 9 servers and ubuntu servers running on Hyper-V. The Debian servers perform as expected with dynamic memory and jump around between 512mb and 2gb of memory. My ubuntu servers seem to jump straight to the max memory available about 15seconds after a reboot. I believe it's all in cache but I'm not an expert in Linux. Flushing the cache it fills up again before the memory shrinks anyway. Can I get some pointers in chasing this down, A lot of work involved changing these newer servers back to Debian.

according to this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/Supported-Ubuntu-virtual-machines-on-Hyper-V 
I need to the article "Applications that tend to consume the entire available memory on a system are limited to consuming up to 80 percent of available RAM."

How can you possibly stop the disk cache expanding.
I have tried echo 512000 > /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes and have the memory pressure set to 400, but the cache just keeps eating GB of ram.

Thanks in advance.

```
#free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        4026308     1558392     1478392       73488      989524     2331652
Swap:       2097148         780     2096368

#slabtop
  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME
116466 111417   0%    0.19K   2773       42     22184K dentry
 83820  83820 100%    0.13K   1397       60     11176K kernfs_node_cache
 66630  65980   0%    1.06K   2221       30     71072K ext4_inode_cache
 63616  63171   0%    0.50K    994       64     31808K kmalloc-512
 55808  54321   0%    0.06K    872       64      3488K pid
 48009  48009 100%    0.10K   1231       39      4924K buffer_head
 44733  44148   0%    0.20K   1147       39      9176K vm_area_struct
 35351  34589   0%    0.59K    667       53     21344K inode_cache
 31808  31211   0%    0.25K    497       64      7952K filp
 30314  29997   0%    0.09K    659       46      2636K anon_vma
 28928  28928 100%    0.03K    226      128       904K kmalloc-32
 25856  25420   0%    0.06K    404       64      1616K kmalloc-64
 18522  18522 100%    0.19K    441       42      3528K cred_jar
 16408  15088   0%    0.57K    293       56      9376K radix_tree_node
 14790  14790 100%    0.04K    145      102       580K ext4_extent_status
 13312  13312 100%    0.02K     52      256       208K kmalloc-16
 11264  11264 100%    0.01K     22      512        88K kmalloc-8
 10608   9571   0%    0.66K    221       48      7072K proc_inode_cache
 10416   9761   0%    0.09K    248       42       992K kmalloc-96
  9920   9483   0%    0.25K    155       64      2480K kmalloc-256
  7084   7040   0%    0.69K    154       46      4928K sock_inode_cache
  6970   6970 100%    0.02K     41      170       164K lsm_file_cache
  5460   5460 100%    0.19K    130       42      1040K kmalloc-192
  4704   4449   0%    1.00K    147       32      4704K kmalloc-1024
```